# K8s - How to pass stored certificate to file path?

Tags: kubernetes, ssl-certificate

I want to pass a certificate which is stored in the cluster as a secret. I have this piece of code failing:

```
method(param1, param2, os.environ['CERTIFICATE']){
     # param1: Does something
     # param2: Does something
     # param3: local path to pem cert used for auth

}
```

Error is that "File name too long: '---BEGIN PRIVATE KEY---...........'". I think - param3 requires a file path, but because I pass the certificate content directly as an environment variable, and not a file path which references the cert - it fails.

Not sure if mounting the secret as volume would make any difference. The cert is stored as follows, I only need tls.key:

```
    Type:  kubernetes.io/tls

Data
====
tls.crt:  1880 bytes
tls.key:  5204 bytes
```

Comment: you need to provide the file path to method parameter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you exposing the private key in an environment variable if your application expects a file? Just [mount the secret as a file](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/distribute-credentials-secure/#create-a-pod-that-has-access-to-the-secret-data-through-a-volume) instead. If you have a Secret named "my-secret" with keys `tls.crt` and `tls.key`, then you can do something like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: example
spec:
  volumes:
  - name: my-secret
    secret:
      secretName: my-secret
  containers:
  - name: example
    image: my-image
    volumeMounts:
    - name: my-secret
      mountPath: "/certificate"
```

This would result in the container having the certificate and key mounted at `/certificate/tls.crt` and `/certificate/tls.key`.

Answer (score 1):

Secrets should be passed to containers as mounted volumes.Mount the secret as a volume in your pod. The configuration data will appear in files available to the container file system

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata: 
  name: volume-pod
spec:
  containers:
  - name: express-test
    image: image-name
    volumeMounts:
    - name: secret-volume
      mountPath: /etc/config/secret
  volumes:
  - name: secret-volume
    secret:
      secretName: my-secret
  command: ["my-command"]
  args: ["param1", "param2", "/etc/certs/tls.key"]
```

The Secret "/etc/certs/tls.key" is mounted on /etc/config/secret, all the files created by the secret volume mount have permission 0400